# What is the opposite of 'brand new'?

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

Is there a phrase that means "very old" but using another adverb instead of "very"? like "brand" in "brand new".

Comment: It does depend a lot on context - *ancient*, *dusty*, *dog-eared*, *well-thumbed*, *antediluvian* and many others can suggest old or well-worn. What are you trying to convey?

Comment: you have to figure out the opposite of 'brand' in this context

Comment: @ProfYaffle no context in particular. just the most generally used one

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an overstatement, you might say **"old as the hills"** or **"older than Mathuselah"**

> - [**Mathuselah"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methuselah) - is the man reported to have lived the longest at the age of 969 in the Hebrew Bible.

This refers more to age than appearance, though. If you are more concerned with appearance, "worn-out" may fit.